# How does signal 4G dial as a Wi-Fi signal through tethering?

Tags: integrated-circuit, signal, mobile

I am looking for the datasheet (internal circuits of embedded mobile) of 4G modules, and I would like to understand how this module, electronically, is connected to the wi-fi module in the same phone.
The 4G allows me to use the mobile connection of a mobile operator, but then, if I want to use this connection through my computer, I need to share this signal in 'tethering' (phone as modem), but this last signal uses another protocol and another frequency range (Wi-Fi)

What is the bridge circuit that join the wi-fi module with the 4g module at electronically way ?

I would like to see diagrams, internal circuits to see if it is an operational amplifier to handle this 'switch' between 4G and Wi-Fi signals and how these signals are management at low electronic level at same time like *services*

I'm interested also on the internal firmware circuits, especially at the point where the 4G signal is 'hooked' as a Wi-Fi signal which is then shared with end users.

Comment: More than likely there is no direct electrical connection: just like in your router or modem, there is no requirement for one communications circuit and another to be wired together. It certainly isn't done using an opamp. Instead the packets arriving on one interface are normally buffered and retransmitted on the other. This is done using two separate interfaces and a microprocessor/memory to deal with the forwarding between them. I'm not sure what "firmware circuits" are, but you will not get details of firmware or circuits for any commercial device: this is proprietary information.

Comment: I find [SDIO interface](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/WiFi-CellularIntegration_AppNote_%28UBX-14003264%29.pdf) like a  *dedicated to communication between the u-blox cellular module and the u-blox short range Wi-Fi module*. This seems a way to communicate between cellular and wifi modules on the same circuit phones, but for internet connection sheet talk about a bridge **PDP
contexts/EPS bearers** (pag 15), but don't show electronical circuit of this *bridge*

Comment: The premise of this question is fairly mistaken. Mobile and WiFi networks can be implemented in different physical chips, or sometimes in the same chip. But that's mostly irrelevant as the path between them is a full receive path and software unpacking to IP level packets, a pass through a rules engine running under the operating system that decides if they're eligible to be passed on, and then a full software packing and transmit flow for the other network. The only thing that really makes tethering distinct from simply using either network is this routing software, and that's off topic here.

Comment: Of course it does not contain any circuit for this object, which exists only as a software concept. In fact if you had read any further you would know that PDP stands for **packet data protocol** and EPS stands for **evolved packet system**. They are purely virtual objects with no direct implementation as circuits.

Comment: mm..ok, but is possible to understand how CPU *handle routing the data between the Wi-Fi module and the cellular network* at electronical circuit level (hardware) not in software way ? I want to see the circuits of mobile-wi-fi`implemented in different physical chips`

Comment: No. More is different. Just as the concepts of electronic circuits do not derive from a study of the motion of individual electrons in semiconductor devices, so software does not have specialized circuits as its basis. General-purpose computing devices are built up from many simple circuits operating together to produce a more complex result. Think of it like the distinction between you as a person and the millions of individual cells making up your body. Similiarly, you would not understand anything about software by looking at circuits consisting of millions of transistors.

Comment: Yes, but there must be a common base, a matrix between the electronic circuits and software event management. A mediation must exist, a bridge layer.. or not exists ?

Answer (score 2):

The Wi-Fi and 4G modules in your phone are not directly connected when you are tethering. They remain as separate devices, one handling a 4G connection, the other handling a Wi-Fi connection. There's certainly no "operational amplifier" connecting them.

In both devices (Wi-Fi and 4G) there will be some front end circuitry that handles conversion from a baseband digital signal to a modulated wireless signal and vice versa. The protocols and frequencies are different, but the function is in essence the same - take some digital data and send it wirelessly, receive some data wirelessly and output digital data.

In terms of how tethering works, basically it is no different from how a network router works. Data comes in on one interface and is then processed by the CPU and sent back out the other interface. The "bridge circuit" in a phone as you put it is basically just the CPU and memory controllers.

Think of it this way:

1. A device connected to your Wi-Fi hotspot says "I want to access data from EE.SE".
2. The Wi-Fi modem in your phone says to the CPU, "This guy wants to access EE.SE, can you get the data for me".
3. The CPU says to the 4G modem "Go get me data from EE.SE". At this point the 4G modem is downloading EE.SE - it doesn't know or care that someone on the Wi-Fi hotspot wanted the data, it is just doing what the CPU asked of it.
4. The data from the internet is downloaded and given back to the CPU by the 4G modem.
5. The CPU says to the Wi-Fi, "I've got the data you wanted. Don't ask me where it came from, you'll want to keep your hands clean when this thing goes sideways".
6. The Wi-Fi modem gives the data to the device that asked for it.

The Wi-Fi modem doesn't care where the data came from, just that it has it. The 4G modem doesn't care who wanted the data, just that it needed to fetch it.

Comment: I find [SDIO interface](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/products/documents/WiFi-CellularIntegration_AppNote_%28UBX-14003264%29.pdf) like a  *dedicated to communication between the u-blox cellular module and the u-blox short range Wi-Fi module*. This seems a way to communicate between cellular and wifi modules on the same circuit phones, but for internet connection sheet talk about a bridge **PDP
contexts/EPS bearers** (pag 15), but don't show electronical circuit of this *bridge*

Comment: @user3520363 SDIO is just a digital interface. Nothing special, and not specific to the application - it's the same interface used in SD cards I believe. You still have a CPU in the cellular module you linked to which will handle routing the data between the Wi-Fi module and the cellular network.

Comment: mm..ok, but is possible to understand how CPU *handle routing the data between the Wi-Fi module and the cellular network* at electronical circuit level (hardware) not in software way ?

Comment: @user3520363 The same way a CPU handles routing data from anywhere to anywhere else. It reads the data from one place and stores it to another. Might be worth looking up the term memory mapped peripherals. At a hardware level you would be looking into generic CPU architectures, data bus architectures, etc.

Comment: It's not "at the electronical circuit level".  It's done with software, and that's off topic here.  Look at the AOSP sources for Android if you want to see example details, but beware, they're tens of gigabytes which makes finding specific things a challenge.  Actually what you might really want to do is look at archives of various DIY tethering hacks on rooted phone from the early days before this was a built in feature, as at least then you'll see the pieces actually used.

Comment: Sorry, but software is an hardware implementation ? - so you just tell me that software at hardware level is a memory mapped register allocation ? Maybe Is there a dedicated part about this memory mapping/CPU register stores when network data is active between cellular & Wi-Fi modules ?

Comment: @user3520363 there is nothing special going on here. Data is just data. It doesn't matter whether it comes from a Wi-Fi module, a hard drive, or a mouse chewing on a cable. That's the whole point of memory mapped architecture. As far as the CPU and any software running on it is concerned, everything is just memory - it can read to it, or it can write to it, or both. In C code for example it is nothing more special than `int* memory = ADDRESS_OF_WIFI; int *morememory = ADDRESS_OF_4G; *morememory = *memory;`.

Comment: ok, so 'software' is just 'memory allocation management' by automation hardware techniques ? But Why I can't understand the signal fragments matching to particular instruction of C (for example) that working in real time  - why is not possible to reconstruct the path of signal when I use software and find that particular event on electrically side ? Why is so complex ?

Comment: You can't understand a software flow from a circuit diagram because in **general purpose stored program computing devices** the *same* circuit paths are used for many *different* purposes.  This is really not a valid question for this site, so you need to drop it now.

Comment: *the same circuit paths are used for many different purposes* - sorry but this is not completely true because same circuit paths are not works *in same times* otherwise is a superposition, in CPU we talk about a clock signal so time is fundamental to manage events but time is a periodic function but if same events are used to build paths not same function is used to make the difference between same hardware events. I need to access to function, not to decrypt circuit combination. So maybe I need to access the elements that control - generate functions like Operational amplifier

Comment: @user3520363 I'm giving up now. You need to go away and research how CPUs work. Thing about this though: you can change the software that is running on the CPU on the fly - it can process whatever instructions you tell it to. But the hardware is fixed when it is made (everything is connected with data buses and address buses), so the same hardware must be capable of doing different tasks all governed by what instructions you execute on the CPU. What's more, op-amps are analog not digital. You won't be able to work out how instructions relate to op-amps because there are no op amps in your CPU.